# While creating channel getting this error?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create channel. But while creating channel I am getting error.

> 2018-09-11 13:57:37.378 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>   Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

I am not getting, what is the problem here. I am trying to create a custom network, so for this i have taken for this reference - https://github.com/CATechnologies/blockchain-tutorials/wiki/Tutorial:-Hyperledger-Fabric-v1.1-–-Create-a-Development-Business-Network-on-zLinux

I am following same step for channel creation also, but I am getting that error. Please suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

Printing Ordere Logs It is giving this error:

> 2018-09-11 15:18:39.291 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 027 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.indirasoft.com")) for identity 0a074f7267314d535012a2062d2d2d2d2d424547494e2043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a4d494943496a434341636d674177494241674952414c4c53597278764b4f753075616c6b557a61457a315177436759494b6f5a497a6a3045417749776554454c0a4d416b474131554542684d4356564d78457a415242674e5642416754436b4e6862476c6d62334a7561574578466a415542674e564241635444564e68626942470a636d467559326c7a593238784844416142674e5642416f54453239795a7a45756157356b61584a686332396d6443356a62323078487a416442674e5642414d540a466d4e684c6d39795a7a45756157356b61584a686332396d6443356a623230774868634e4d5467774f5445784d544d304f5449785768634e4d6a67774f5441340a4d544d304f544978576a42654d517377435159445651514745774a56557a45544d4245474131554543424d4b5132467361575a76636d3570595445574d4251470a4131554542784d4e5532467549455a795957356a61584e6a627a45694d434147413155454177775a515752746157354162334a6e4d533570626d5270636d467a0a62325a304c6d4e766254425a4d424d4742797147534d34394167454743437147534d34394177454841304941424f7244714b35334e30643272563945345641430a32595345477043324d533467306d5556694b47576961704d48624c6a7979492b53386b424476476547554d4e446f66383650736a75735a7864554435556a54350a4957576a5454424c4d41344741315564447745422f775145417749486744414d42674e5648524d4241663845416a41414d437347413155644977516b4d434b410a494d673871332b326f2f4d67327445635842734436577076324a3059367338304c6c6c41372f4d64353079534d416f4743437147534d343942414d43413063410a4d455143494437363374376d656f67424e6843767862394f79347732744e5a4b4d416c4651714f5557627836362f324e416942796c38657877786561335861360a2b6242316131624f47416c58746f4933486a76765943457a364c43624c773d3d0a2d2d2d2d2d454e442043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a
>   2018-09-11 15:18:39.291 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 028 Obtaining identity
>   2018-09-11 15:18:39.292 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 029 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.indirasoft.com")) for identity 0a074f7267314d535012a2062d2d2d2d2d424547494e2043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a4d494943496a434341636d674177494241674952414c4c53597278764b4f753075616c6b557a61457a315177436759494b6f5a497a6a3045417749776554454c0a4d416b474131554542684d4356564d78457a415242674e5642416754436b4e6862476c6d62334a7561574578466a415542674e564241635444564e68626942470a636d467559326c7a593238784844416142674e5642416f54453239795a7a45756157356b61584a686332396d6443356a62323078487a416442674e5642414d540a466d4e684c6d39795a7a45756157356b61584a686332396d6443356a623230774868634e4d5467774f5445784d544d304f5449785768634e4d6a67774f5441340a4d544d304f544978576a42654d517377435159445651514745774a56557a45544d4245474131554543424d4b5132467361575a76636d3570595445574d4251470a4131554542784d4e5532467549455a795957356a61584e6a627a45694d434147413155454177775a515752746157354162334a6e4d533570626d5270636d467a0a62325a304c6d4e766254425a4d424d4742797147534d34394167454743437147534d34394177454841304941424f7244714b35334e30643272563945345641430a32595345477043324d533467306d5556694b47576961704d48624c6a7979492b53386b424476476547554d4e446f66383650736a75735a7864554435556a54350a4957576a5454424c4d41344741315564447745422f775145417749486744414d42674e5648524d4241663845416a41414d437347413155644977516b4d434b410a494d673871332b326f2f4d67327445635842734436577076324a3059367338304c6c6c41372f4d64353079534d416f4743437147534d343942414d43413063410a4d455143494437363374376d656f67424e6843767862394f79347732744e5a4b4d416c4651714f5557627836362f324e416942796c38657877786561335861360a2b6242316131624f47416c58746f4933486a76765943457a364c43624c773d3d0a2d2d2d2d2d454e442043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a
>   2018-09-11 15:18:39.292 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 02a [channel: indirasoft-channel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.19.0.13:51492 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
>   2018-09-11 15:18:39.293 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 02b Error reading from 172.19.0.13:51490: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Comment: Can you post more information? Like configtx.yaml file, the step you generate your crypto-config and channel-artifacts.

Comment: Basically telling you that the certificate you are trying to use is not known to the orderer. This can be due to a number of circumstances. Possibly, you had an orderer service running from a previous test and when you tried to start-up a new network, it used the old orderer service (and all its config) with peers configured with newly generated certificates. You might want to ensure that any prior network components are no longer running when you start a new network.